# Cannot save into db using prepared statement

Tags: php, mysql

I cannot save in my db using prepared statements. I don't know what the problem is with this code:

```
$stmt3 = $this->db->prapare("INSERT INTO criminal(investigation, isFujitive, suspect_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
$stmt3->bind_param('sii', $lastSeen[$i], $isFujitive[$i], $id);
if ($stmt3->execute()){
    echo "Working";
}
```

I checked already if the db is empty using this code:

```
$db = $this->db;
if(empty($db)){
   $this->connect();
   $db = $this->db;
}
```

But then again there is no output and cannot save in db.

Comment: You're calling the `prapare` method instead of `prepare`.

Comment: Maybe turn on error reporting.

Comment: your right that is my problem.. thank you SolarBear

Comment: Still doesn't save.. I turn on error reporting but still doesn't save

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
$stmt3 = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO criminal(investigation, isFujitive,    suspect_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
if ($stmt3->execute(array($lastSeen[$i], $isFujitive[$i], $id)){
    echo "Working";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Either one will work

```
$stmt3 = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO criminal(investigation, isFujitive, suspect_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
$stmt3->bindParam(1, $lastSeen[$i]);
$stmt3->bindParam(2, $isFujitive[$i]);
$stmt3->bindParam(3, $id);
$stmt3->execute();
```

Or

```
$stmt3 = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO criminal(investigation, isFujitive, suspect_id) VALUES (:inv, :fuj, :sus)");
$stmt3->bindParam('inv', $lastSeen[$i]);
$stmt3->bindParam('fuj', $isFujitive[$i]);
$stmt3->bindParam('sus', $id);
$stmt3->execute();
```

Or

```
$stmt3 = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO criminal(investigation, isFujitive, suspect_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
$stmt3->execute(array($lastSeen[$i], $isFujitive[$i], $id));
```

Luca